# ssh: connect to host 128.114.126.232 port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: unix, ssh, connection, out, timed

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to ssh into the target remote host. I've attempted to shh in from two different computers to no avail. A solution I've found looking around was to redirect to a different port, but I receive this error again but with the new port number. Below is the debug information:

```
bash-4.1$ ssh -vvv oniemann@128.114.126.232
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 128.114.126.232 [128.114.126.232] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 128.114.126.232 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 128.114.126.232 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any ideas on where the problem might be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the server has port 22 blocked. There may be an explicit port that allows ssh via the host servers firewall settings. This is a common practice, as port 22 is the default port. Are you able to access the terminal via LISH? if so, you could check the port rules from there, I'd be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from one of the two places.

1. The server you are trying to reach is not listening for incoming ssh connection requests on port 22
2. There is some sort of a firewall between the machine you are on and the server you are trying to ssh into, blocking port 22 traffic.

If you are the server admin for 128.114.126.232 and you know that ssh is configured properly, your culprit is #2. Considering this machine is located in UC Santa Cruz (if the IP address you provided is real) there is a high likelihood that, certain network segments are segregated from each other by firewalls.